# Getting errors when converting a text file to VCF format

Tags: python, csv

I have a python code where I am trying to convert a text file containing variant information in the rows to a variant call format file (vcf) for my downstream analysis.

I am getting everything correct but when I am trying to run the code I miss out the first two entries , I mean the first two rows. The code is below, The line which is not reading the entire file is highlighted. I would like some expert advice.

I just started coding in python so I am not well versed entirely with it.

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##fileDate=20140901
##source=dbSNP
##dbSNP_BUILD_ID=137
##reference=hg19
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO

import sys

text=open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
print text
print "First print"
text=filter(lambda x:x.split('\t')[31].strip()=='KEEP',text[2:])
print text
print "################################################"
text=map(lambda x:x.split('\t')[0]+'\t'+x.split('\t')[1]+'\t.\t'+x.split('\t')[2]+'\t'+x.split('\t')[3]+'\t.\tPASS\t.\n',text)
print text
file=open(sys.argv[1].replace('.txt','.vcf'),'w')

file.write('##fileformat=VCFv4.0\n')
file.write('##source=dbSNP')
file.write('##dbSNP_BUILD_ID=137')
file.write('##reference=hg19\n')
file.write('#CHROM\tPOS\tID\tREF\tALT\tQUAL\tFILTER\tINFO\n')

for i in text:
        file.write(i)
        file.close()
```

**INPUT:**

```
chrM    152 T   C   T_S7998 N_S8980 0   DBSNP   COVERED 1   1   1   282 36  0   163.60287   0.214008    0.02    11.666081   202 55  7221    1953    0   0   TT  14.748595   49  0   1786    0   KEEP
chr9    311 T   C   T_S7998 N_S8980 0   NOVEL   COVERED 0.993882    0.999919    0.993962    299 0   0   207.697923  1   0.02    1.854431    0   56  0   1810    1   116 CC  -44.649001  0   12  0   390 KEEP
chr13   440 C   T   T_S7998 N_S8980 0   NOVEL   COVERED 1   1   1   503 7   0   4.130339    0.006696    0.02    4.124606    445 3   16048   135 0   0   CC  12.942762   40  0   1684    0   KEEP
```

**OUTPUT desired:**

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##source=dbSNP##dbSNP_BUILD_ID=137##reference=hg19
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO
chrM    152 .   T   C   .   PASS    .
chr9    311 .   T   C   .   PASS    .
chr13   440 .   C   T   .   PASS    .
```

**OUTPUT obtained:**

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##source=dbSNP##dbSNP_BUILD_ID=137##reference=hg19
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO
chr13   440 .   C   T   .   PASS    .
```

I would like to have some help regarding how this error can be rectified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code

1. In the `filter` function you are passing `text[2:]`. I think you want to pass `text` to get all the rows.
2. In the last loop where you write to the .vcf file, you are closing the file inside the loop. You should first write all the values and then close the file outside the loop.

So your code will look like (I removed all the prints):

```
import sys
text=open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
text=filter(lambda x:x.split('\t')[31].strip()=='KEEP',text) # Pass text
text=map(lambda x:x.split('\t')[0]+'\t'+x.split('\t')[1]+'\t.\t'+x.split('\t')[2]+'\t'+x.split('\t')[3]+'\t.\tPASS\t.\n',text)
file=open(sys.argv[1].replace('.txt','.vcf'),'w')

file.write('##fileformat=VCFv4.0\n')
file.write('##source=dbSNP')
file.write('##dbSNP_BUILD_ID=137')
file.write('##reference=hg19\n')
file.write('#CHROM\tPOS\tID\tREF\tALT\tQUAL\tFILTER\tINFO\n')

for i in text:
    file.write(i)
file.close() # close after writing all the values, in the end
```

Comment: Good to know that it works now. Accept the answer if you think it helped you !